# Composer issue with PHP?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm getting the following error when trying to run any composer command? I've tried the following commands, but none seem to want to work

I've tried

```
composer install <package>
```

Also tried

```
composer update
```

Also tried

```
composer self-update
```

Here is the error I get:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint #: Invalid version string "#"
```

This happened after running composer init and making my composer.json file.

Comment: Are you running composer on your local machine or on Homebrew?  You could also try running `composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.3@dev`

Comment: Can you please show the contents of your `composer.json` file?